# Vundle not installing properly

Tags: vim

It seems like not all the plugins are installing properly. I have the following log file:

```
[2015-09-30 14:58:32] Plugin user/L9                                                                      |~                                                                                                         
[2015-09-30 14:58:32] $ git clone --recursive 'https://github.com/user/L9.git' '/home/sachin/.vim/bundle/n|~                                                                                                         
ewL9'                                                                                                     |~                                                                                                         
[2015-09-30 14:58:32] > Cloning into '/home/sachin/.vim/bundle/newL9'...                                  |~                                                                                                         
[2015-09-30 14:58:32] > remote: Repository not found.                                                     |~                                                                                                         
[2015-09-30 14:58:32] > fatal: repository 'https://github.com/user/L9.git/' not found                     Username for 'https://github.com': sachinruk                                                               
[2015-09-30 14:58:32] >                                                                                   |~                                                                                                         
[2015-09-30 14:58:33]                                                                                     |~                                                                                                         
[2015-09-30 14:58:33] Helptags:                                                                           |~                                                                                                         
[2015-09-30 14:58:33] :helptags /home/sachin/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/doc                                   |~                                                                                                         
[2015-09-30 14:58:33] :helptags /home/sachin/.vim/bundle/vim-fugitive/doc                                 |~                                                                                                         
[2015-09-30 14:58:33] :helptags /home/sachin/.vim/bundle/L9/doc                                           |~                                                                                                         
[2015-09-30 14:58:33] :helptags /home/sachin/.vim/bundle/command-t/doc                                    |~                                                                                                         
[2015-09-30 14:58:33] Helptags: 4 plugins processed
```

And my .vimrc file is this:

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
" plugin on GitHub repo
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
" plugin from http://vim-scripts.org/vim/scripts.html
Plugin 'L9'
" Git plugin not hosted on GitHub
Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'    
Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
" Avoid a name conflict with L9
Plugin 'user/L9', {'name': 'newL9'}

call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

Its obvious that there is no https://github.com/user/L9 page but I'm not quite sure what it is that I am doing wrong. It asks for my github username and password before it fails.

More importantly do I need to worry about this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you don't need to worry about the error. You seem to have copied the VIMRC from the readme, that the readme is for illustration purposes. you should Remove plugins you don't need. below is the empty Vundle config.
This is all you need.

```
set nocompatible 
filetype off

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

Now if you want to add a new plugin example 
[nerdtree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree)

you just add the line

**`Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'`**

now the vimrc will look like this

```
set nocompatible 
filetype off

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
" added nerdtree
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

Now, just save the vimrc and restart vim so it can source the new vimrc then issue the **:PluginInstall command:**

```
:PluginInstall
```

more information on using can be found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-vundle-to-manage-vim-plugins-on-a-linux-vps)